Issue in the laravel.yml file using github action pages
I have react laravel project. Repo name is UBI. Inside it two folders, ubi for frontend in react, live on AWS amplify, but other is api that is laravel. Here is the copy of laravel.yml file and when the GitHub action pages run this laravel.yml, it fails to find the composer.json that is inside the api folder.
This is the copy of my larave.yml file:
name: Laravel

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@15c43e89cdef867065b0213be354c2841860869e
      with:
        php-version: '8.2'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Navigate to Laravel directory
      run: cd api
    - name: Copy .env
      run: php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
    - name: List directory contents
      run: ls -la
    - name: Navigate to Laravel directory
      run: cd api/
    - name: List directory contents
      run: ls -la
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: composer install
      # run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist
    - name: Generate key
      run: php artisan key:generate
    - name: Directory Permissions
      run: chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    - name: Create Database
      run: |
        mysql -h localhost -u root --password=root -e "CREATE DATABASE laravel_test;"
        php artisan migrate --seed --env=testing
    - name: Execute tests (Unit and Feature tests) via PHPUnit/Pest
      env:
        DB_CONNECTION: mysql
        DB_HOST: localhost
        DB_PORT: 3306
        DB_DATABASE: laravel_test
        DB_USERNAME: root
        DB_PASSWORD: root
      run: php artisan test

Issue is in moving to directory by cd api, As it is printing the files of that directory before and after navigatin, although it does not changes directory.

You may use working-directory or combine those commands into multiline run.

You may list the home folder before making calling cd api command so you get a verbose result of the folder content
Not sure, but maybe you can use this option path: api under actions/checkout@v4
